# (Not Clipping Issue) Why are my 'image as plane' branches disappearing when the game camera gets too close?

Tags: particles, camera

I've followed this [nice tutorial on how to make a tree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o54gVHUPdCU&t=552s) that's given me the results I want in UPBGE. To create the branches, I used a .png and applied it to the branches as a particle system. When I navigate the world through my in-game camera, the branches look great at a distance; when I get really close to the lowest-hanging branch, however, the leaves closest to me start to disappear. This is true of the particle branches, and of the original 'image as plane' that I used to create them. The low branch stays visible no matter how close the camera is, and I believe I've turned clipping down as far as it will go.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I just want the branches to stay consistently visible even when my camera is super close to them. Thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I've uploaded the file and added a link in the comment below.

Answer (score 1):

That's called **Camera Clipping** and it can be set under `N-Panel (press N) > View > CLip Start` and `Clip End`. Here you want to change `Start` to something really low like `0.1 cm`. NOTE: While you can only drag the Start slider to 0.1, you can still edit the value to something even lower.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, but I don't think it's a clipping issue: as I mentioned above, my 'start' for clipping was set really low (0.001 m), and the branch doesn't clip when I'm close to it, only the particle branches and image as planes disappear when the camera comes close.  I've uploaded the file here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=oNrxdqn1" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/oNrxdqn1/)